# Remove trailing slash redirect loop

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I am using the following to remove the trailing slash:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]


</VirtualHost>
```

However, whenever I access my homepage  (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`) I get a redirect loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]


</VirtualHost>
```

Use + instead of *